# remove white spaces from a 2D array using python

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array

how can i remove white spaces in my 2D array using python..i have written my code like below..
code:

```
 MI_feature_matrix_POS = [["" for x in xrange(2)] for x in xrange(1000)]
 ##### perform some opeation and assign some values into the matrix..and sort the matrix
 sorted_MI_feature_rank_list = sorted ( MI_feature_matrix, key=lambda MI_feature_matrix: MI_feature_matrix[0], reverse = False )
      sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS=filter(None, sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS)
      numrows = len(sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS)
      for i in range(0,numrows):
          print sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS[i]


> output:
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     []
>     ['addicted', '0.00010118008040085441']
>     ['admitted', '0.00010118008040085441']
>     ['age', '0.00010118008040085441']
>     ['anecdote', '0.00010118008040085441']
>     ['arguement', '0.00010118008040085441']
>     ['banana', '0.00010118008040085441']
```

....

i want to remove the this white spaces from this matrix?is it possible??

Comment: Where are you using `MI_feature_matrix_POS`?

Comment: that is my orginal matrix befor sort..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` with no function argument:

```
filter(None, sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS)
```

Comment: I see the same statement in the question.

Comment: If you're curious, this works because the empty list `[]` evaluates to False, so you don't need to specify a lambda function, the natural semantics of lists work for you.

Comment: @thefourtheye I think he updated the question to include this answer

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS = [i for i in sorted_MI_feature_rank_list_POS if i]
```